# Rational solutions of quadratic Diophantine equation $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+du^2=v^2$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, diophantine-approximation

What do we know about the rational solutions of quadratic Diophantine equation  $ax^2+by^2+cz^2+du^2=v^2$ in five variables $x,y,z,u,v$?

I am looking for references/papers related to this equation.

Comment: There is a lot known. On this site you'll find almost $100$ posts related to it, with many special cases, e.g., for integers with arbitrary many squares [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466870), or for $2$ square, $3$ squares and $4$ squares separately (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738446/solutions-to-ax2-by2-cz2)).

Comment: Special cases as "consecutive integers" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191312/when-is-a-sum-of-consecutive-squares-equal-to-a-square/3143349#3143349), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790680/sum-of-two-consecutive-squares-equal-square/1790786), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the references but they are very specialized cases.

Comment: They are all valid cases of your equation because you allow $a=0$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+du^2=v^2$
Let assume $a+b+c+d=r^2.$
$p,q$ are arbitrary.
Substitute  $x=pt+1, y=qt+1, z=pt-1, u=qt-1, v=t+r$  to above equation, then we get  $$t = \frac{2(ap-qr^2+qa+2bq+qc-cp-r)}{(-ap^2-q^2r^2+q^2a+q^2c-cp^2+1)}.$$
Thus, we get a parametric solution below.
\begin{eqnarray}
  &x& = (a-3c)p^2+(2qc-2qr^2+2qa+4bq-2r)p+q^2a+q^2c+1-q^2r^2 \\ 
  &y& = (-a-c)p^2+(2qa-2qc)p+3q^2c-3q^2r^2+3q^2a+4bq^2+1-2qr \\ 
  &z& = (3a-c)p^2+(2qc-2qr^2+2qa+4bq-2r)p-q^2a-q^2c-1+q^2r^2 \\ 
  &u& = (c+a)p^2+(2qa-2qc)p+q^2c-q^2r^2+q^2a+4bq^2-1-2qr \\ 
  &v& = (-ra-rc)p^2+(2a-2c)p+2qc-2qr^2+2qa+4bq-q^2r^3+rq^2a-r+rq^2c.  
\end{eqnarray}
Example for $(a,b,c,d,r)=(1,2,3,3,3).$
\begin{eqnarray}
&x& = -8p^2+(-2q-6)p+1-5q^2\\
&y& = -4p^2-4qp-7q^2-6q+1\\
&z& = (-2q-6)p+5q^2-1\\
&u& = 4p^2-4qp+3q^2-6q-1\\
&v& = -12p^2-4p-2q-3-15q^2
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

indefinite forms in at least five variables are isotropic. There is an integer solution, not all variables zero.

If you are not worried about common divisors, you can parametrize all rational solutions by stereographic projection around a fixed solution.

Comment: How should I start such a parametrization? Should it look like a rational parametrization of sphere given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777790/rational-parametrization-of-points-on-sphere-of-irrational-radius)