# How to characterize the rational points on a sphere of radius $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, rational-numbers, rational-functions

Let's take a $3$ dimensional sphere of radius $r$, such as $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$.

For $r^2=1$, all the rational points of the sphere (i.e. points for which all coordinates are rational numbers) are characterised by

\begin{equation}
x=\frac{2p}{p^2+q^2+1};y=\frac{2q}{p^2+q^2+1};z=\frac{p^2+q^2-1}{p^2+q^2+1}
\end{equation}

with $p$ and $q$ rationals.

For $r^2 = 2$,  using [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777790/rational-parametrization-of-points-on-sphere-of-irrational-radius), one can show that

$$x=uz+1; y=vz+1; z=-2 {\frac {u+v}{{v}^{2}+{u}^{2}+1}}$$

with $u,v$ integers.

How would one do to find the rational characterisation when $r^2 = 3$?

Comment: Exactly the same way. Given any degree-2 hypersurface with a rational point (in this case, $(1,1,1)$), there's a bijection between rational points on the hypersurface and rational lines through the chosen rational point. This is likely a duplicate, but I can't quite find the appropriate post to mark it as a duplicate of at the moment.

Comment: The general rule is to start with one rational point, and then join rays from that point of rational "slope" and find the other point on the sphere. Starting with $v_0=(-1,-1,-1)$ and an integer vector $a=(p,q,r)$ with $\gcd(p,q,r)=1,$ you want to find another point on the sphere of the form $v_0+at,$ where $t$ is rational. This amounts to solving: $$(-1+pt)^2+(-1+qt)^2+(-1+rt)^2=3$$ or $$2t(p+q+r)=t^2(p^2+q^2+r^2).$$ $t=0$ gives the obvious solution, and there is another solution if $$t=\frac{2(p+q+r)}{p^2+q^2+r^2}.$$

Comment: This gives $$x=\frac{p^2-q^2-r^2+2pq+2pr}{p^2+q^2+r^2}\\y=\frac{q^2-p^2-r^2+2qp+2qr}{p^2+q^2+r^2}\\z=\frac{r^2-p^2-q^2+2rp+2rq}{p^2+q^2+r^2}$$

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you for the catch, I fixed the title.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the catch, I mixed up notations. The one with $r^2=2$ assumes $u,v$ integers, but the one for $r^2 = 1$ assumes they're rationals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Would you like to add your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

well. Finding the rational points by stereographic projection will tend to produce  fractions that reduce to smaller denominators.  Which may not matter to you, of course.

For $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3 d^2 $  in integers, we   find all primitive solutions with $\gcd(w,x,y,z) = 1,$   also $w+x+y+z$ odd,  finally

$$ a = w^2 + x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 0 \, w  x - 2  w  y + 2  x  y + 2  w  z + 2  x  z + 0  \,  y  z $$
$$ b = w^2 - x^2 + y^2 - z^2 + 2  w  x - 0  \,  w  y + 2  x  y - 2  w  z + 0  \,  x  z + 2  y  z$$
$$ c = w^2 - x^2 - y^2 + z^2 - 2  w  x + 2  w  y + 0  \,  x  y + 0  \,  w  z + 2  x  z + 2  y  z$$
$$ d = w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $$

The zero coefficients are on purpose, to keep the spacing.